# Why next code does not compile?

Tags: c++, gio, glibmm

How do i rewrite next sources properly? It is part of GLib-powered IRC-bot. Compiler crashes with the next error:

```
src/irc.cpp:20:9: error: cannot call member function ‘Glib::ListHandle<Glib::RefPtr<Gio::InetAddress> > Gio::Resolver::lookup_by_name(const Glib::ustring&, const Glib::RefPtr<Gio::Cancellable>&)’ without object
     ),
```

Sources:

```
#include "includes.hpp" // Just including all the files

Glib::RefPtr<Gio::Socket> ircSock; // Our socket

void ircInit() { // Init-function
  try {
    ircSock = Gio::Socket::create( // Creating socket
      Gio::SocketFamily::SOCKET_FAMILY_IPV4,
      Gio::SocketType::SOCKET_TYPE_STREAM,
      Gio::SocketProtocol::SOCKET_PROTOCOL_TCP
    );

    ircSock->connect( // Problematic code
      Gio::InetSocketAddress::create(
        Gio::Resolver::lookup_by_name(
          "irc.freenode.net", // For-example
          Gio::Cancellable::create()
        ),
        6667
      ),
      Gio::Cancellable::create()
    );
  } catch(const Glib::Error& e) {
    std::cerr << "IRC: Error: " << e.what() << std::endl; // Error-reporting
  }
}
```

Comment: because it's a member function. You cannot call it like a static function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/stable/classGio_1_1Resolver.html#aea1576fa2684d9bca58a589098a8371e), this is member function, so, you need constructed object to call it, while you are trying to call it like it is static function.

Correct fix would be to create `Gio::Resolver` object, and call this method on created object.

Comment: `src/irc.cpp:19:18: error: request for member ‘lookup_by_name’ in ‘resolver’, which is of non-class type ‘Gio::Resolver()’` (sorry, i am new to C++. Current ver: [here](http://hastebin.com/sasezeroju.php)